How do you change the order of integration in this double integral? I need help
Given integral:
$$
\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{x^2}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx
$$
My solution:
$$
\int_0^4\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
$$
I presumed my solution was right, however when I plugged the given limits and the solution limits into geogebra the domain seemed wrong, I don't know how to solve this correctly.
Sorry for the bad english, it's not my first language.

Draw the picture — by hand, not by computer software. Your limits of integration correspond to the wrong region. You cannot do this by magic; you must draw pictures. Also, if you are planning to interact with people on this site, you should actually type the questions in MathJax and not do mathematics by links.

You have the region above the parabola, but you want the region below the parabola, so you need to split the $dx$ integral into two parts
$$\int_{-2}^{-\sqrt y} \text{ and }  \int_{\sqrt y}^2$$

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

In the image that states the problem, the function $~f(x,y)~$ is not specified.


$\int_{-2}^2 \int_0^{x^2} dx dy$ is yellow.
$\int_0^4 \int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y} dx dy$ is orange.
Orange $\neq$ yellow :-)
